# как рандомно за спавнить один объект из массива GameObject[2]

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
   public class ObsttacleGenerator : MonoBehaviour
    {   
        public GameObject[] prefs;

        void Start () {
            StartCoroutine(timer());

        }

        IEnumerator timer()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 100500; i++)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);

              Instantiate(prefs)//нужно спаунить один из двух объектов 
                                 //каждые 5 секунд
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Random rnd = new Random(); Instantiate(prefs[rnd.Next(2)]);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте данный код:

```
    IEnumerator timer()
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100500; i++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            Instantiate(prefs[rnd.Next(2)]);
        }
    }
```

Подробнее про рандом [тут](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html).

Answer (score 0):

Либо с использованием рандома от `UnityEngine`, а не от `System`

```
IEnumerator timer()
{
    int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, prefs.Length-1) // Получаем случайный индекс из всей длинны массива, любое число от нуля и до конца массива. Сработает не только при двух объектах в массиве, но и при их любом числе. 


    for (int i = 0; i < 100500; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
        Instantiate(prefs[randomIndex]);//Ищем объект в массиве под этим индексом и спауним его. 
    }
}
```